# Bookmarklet to replace the current url with some chars and open in another tab

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm building a bookmarklet and I need to replace some chars in the current URL and open it in another tab when they activate the bookmarklet.

Here is the code

```
javascript:setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('foo', 'bar')}, 200)
```

However, I can only refresh the page in the current tab. how to open the new link in a new tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with Bookmarklets, but try this:

```
javascript:setTimeout(function(){
    const href = window.location.href.replace('foo', 'bar')
    window.open(href)
}, 200)
```

Let me know if it worked.